# How to improve teb when robot facing different directions

Tags: navigation, teb-local-planner

The robot chassis I am using is a steering wheel chassis with four active wheels, when using the teb_local_planner, the speeds planned are different when the chassis is facing different directions. can some modification be made so that the chassis is close to the maximum speed when it is facing different directions?
[image]

[image]